# Recode or compute age categories based by gender

Tags: spss

I'm a complete spss-novice and I can't figure it out. Google doesn't give any answers either (or I don't know how to google this question.. that's possible too).

I have to make a new variable based on two variables:

Gender (0=male, 1=female)
and
oudad (1=age 18-29; 2=age 30-54; 3=age 55-89; 4=deselect 99).

The new variable has to have six categories:
1. 18-29 male
2. 18-29 female
3. 30-54 male
4. 30-54 female
.. and so on.

I think I have to do something with either compute or recode into different variables, but can't figure out what to do.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's the 'correct' way to do it, but this is the way I got it done. Advise on how to improve it, is still appreciated :)

```
IF (gender = 0 & agegroup =1) GenAge=1.
IF (gender = 0 & agegroup =2) GenAge=2.
IF (gender = 0 & agegroup =3) GenAge=3.
IF (gender = 1 & agegroup =1) GenAge=4.
IF (gender = 1 & agegroup =2) GenAge=5.
IF (gender = 1 & agegroup =3) GenAge=6.
EXECUTE.

VALUE  LABELS GenAge 
 1 'Young man'
 2 'Middle-aged man'
 3 'Old man'
 4 'Young woman'
 5 'Middle-aged woman'
 6 'Old woman'.
```

Comment: Using a series of `IF` commands in this way (rather than `DO IF`) requires 6 data passes (in this example - each data pass scans through all rows in the data) to be made whereas the `DO IF` approach requires only a single data pass (it is able to achieve the same computation by scanning through all rows only the once). So for large datasets coding in this way may be detrimental to the speed of the computation. But otherwise both will achieve the same results (which you should notice).

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [`DO IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_if.htm?lang=en) and/or [`IF`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_if.htm?lang=en) command.

```
DO IF (Gender = 0 /* Male*/ AND Age = 1 /* 18 -29 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=1.
ELSE IF (Gender = 1 /* Female */ AND Age = 1 /* 18 -29 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=2.
ELSE IF (Gender = 0 /* Male */ AND Age = 2 /* 30 - 54 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=3.
ELSE IF (Gender = 1 /* Female */ AND Age = 2 /* 30 - 54 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=4.
ELSE IF (Gender = 0 /* Male */ AND Age = 3 /* 55 - 89 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=5.
ELSE IF (Gender = 1 /* Female */ AND Age = 3 /* 55 - 89 */).
    COMPUTE GenAge=6.
END IF.
```

The content between each pair of `/*` & `*/` are simply to help make the code more readable and apparent what the code represents and so entirely optional.

Instead of series of `IF` statements in this manner (which could be even more cumbersome with a large number of categories), I would typically opt for coding something like this in an alternative manner such as follows:

```
RECODE Gender (0=2) (ELSE=COPY).
VALUE LABELS Gender 1 "Female" 2 Male".
COMPUTE GenAge=SUM(Gender*10, Age).
VALUE LABELS GenAge.
  11 "Female 18 - 29"
  12 "Female 30 - 54"
  13 "Female 55 - 89"
  21 "Male 18 - 29"
  22 "Male 30 - 54"
  23 "Male 55 - 89".
```

For categorical variables of this nature it is typically irrelevant the code that is assigned to it so I would always prefer a solution which involves writing as little code as possible and that too not being dependent on the data itself too. If the order is of importance you could always choose to have `Age` represented by the tenth unit integer and `Gender` the single unit integer.

Comment: Can you explain the exact actions I have to take, instead of only the syntax or code? Because when I try your solution I get a bunch of errors from spss, and I have to be able to do it via the program instead of only via syntax.

So compute, then select variable x, then (...) and so on. Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In terms of errors you are getting when running the code, I would suspect this is because the variables I have used for `Gender` and `Age` in the code may be different to what you actually have in your dataset so they would just need to be changed in the syntax to reflect what you have in your dataset. I'll edit my post to give indication how to achieve this using drop-down menus

Comment: Certain commands are not supported using GUI/drop-downs and I believe (as I can't find anything in an attempt to help in this instance) that '`DO IF' command may not be supported. So I would suggest learning syntax.

Comment: In this example one way to do it is `COMPUTE Age2 = oudad*2 - Gender.` since Gender is 0-1 and the age categories start at 1.

Comment: You were right regarding the name of the variables (forgot to change one) but when running the Do if / compute / else if, I get a empty variable (the only thing in the data view is '-'). Same with the recode one.. Learning syntax is fine by me, but we have to show how to do it with spss too. (teachers, sigh!)

Comment: EXE? What do you mean?

Comment: Simply "EXE. " in syntax or CTR+G short cut key whilst in data view

Comment: Adding 'execute' in the syntax gives results, for the DO IF gives only the results '2', '4', '6' (so the 1, 3 and 5 for the male gender is missing) and the recode gives '11', '12', '13', '21', '23'. (maybe more, so far as I can see, weird numbers..)